# In .htaccess, redirect is stripping all CSS from pages

Tags: css, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm setting up a new directory system for my website and I need to 301 anyone who enters one of the old url formats (or clicks and old link) to my new format.

When someone clicks or types

https://www.blahblah.com/checklist/documentname/documentsubtask/

I need them to be 301'd to

https://www.blahblah.com/checklist/documentname/

So this works fine, but when someone trys to load the page normally all of the CSS has been stripped, and the console is ripe with tons of '404 not found' errors for all my CSS, JS and other assets.

Do I need to add an exception to the redirect for anything with 'wp' in it so that my wordpress files arent changed?

Whats happened here, geniuses of the interwebs?

However in the code below, if

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /checklist/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /checklist/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule . /checklist/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In the `<head>` of the page, are the `.css`, `.js` and other assets linked to via absolute paths, relative-to-root paths or relative paths? (I'm guessing the third option...?)

Comment: Had to correct my comment. My functions.php file inserts the links in ><head>.  Their paths are relative.

Comment: I just noticed in the console, that all of those assets have had '5da048' added to them.